# Find vectors x and y with given norms.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I've spent many hours on this and I just can't understand how to do this. Could you please go through this with me? I have a test, and I really need to understand how to do these types of problems. Thank you so much!!

"Find vectors $x$ an $y$ with $\|x\|_s=1$ and $\|y\|_m=1$
such that $\|A\|_1=\|Ax\|_s$ and $\|A\|_\infty=\|Ay\|_m$, given

$$A=\left[
\begin{matrix}
0&-5&2\\
3&1&-3\\
-4&-4&3
\end{matrix}
\right]"$$

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajIGB.png)

Comment: Isn't max norm and infinity norm the same thing? And the same with sum norm and one norm?

Comment: What are the definitions of these norms?

Comment: @Arthur Presumably the symbols $s$ and $m$ are used for elements of $\mathbb R^3$ whereas the indices $1$ and $\infty$ are reserved for the operator norms of matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The $y$ question is the easier one. The maxima of $\|Ay\|_m$ are reached on the vertices of the unit "ball", which is actually a cube, so you only need to test 8 cases; and it is easy to see that the maximum will be reached in the third coordinate for the unit vector $(-1;-1;+1)$ (use the same signs as the third row of the matrix).

For the $x$ question consider the definition of the sum norm of $Ax$.

$$\|Ax\|_s=\sum_{i=1}^3\left|\sum_{j=1}^3a_{ij}x_j\right|$$

so we are maximizing a linear function on the boundary of the unit "ball", which in this case is a regular octahedron whose 6 vertices are points on the 3 coordinate axes.

The matrix column where the sum of the absolute values is highest, is the second one; therefore the maximum norm is reached at $(0;\pm1;0).$